# How to retrieve meta information updates programmatically

Tags: socrata

I'm looking for a way to check automatically whether meta information of dataset published to Socrata platform is updated.

I'm currently using the data.json in the root of the data publishers URL on Socrate to get some information regarding published datasets. I'm missing a datefield for updates of meta information.

Within data.json I see only datefields for dataset initial creation and latest row updates, for example:
issued  "2016-05-23"
modified    "2017-11-30"

I'm expecting of a possible meta information update date that I'm able to detect structural data changes in a dataset (like added/removed columns for example)

Comment: Hmm. So you're look specifically for structural / DDL changes, or are you looking for all metadata updates like name, description, etc changes as well?

Comment: structural / DDL changes

Comment: Unfortunately you'd need to poll for those periodically from our Catalog or Metadata APIs. There's now way to subscribe to notifications on those changes.